# How to Save The Form We Created

Tags: django

Form.save not working

Hello guys, I created a form myself without using ModelForm self fields to design it on my own by using css and html but at the end form.save not using ı have no idea what to do
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

This is my view,

```
class ContactView(View):
def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    return render(request,'contact.html')



def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    form = Form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        newUser = form.save()
        return redirect('homepage')
    return render(request,'contact.html',{'form':form})
```

This is my html,

```
<form method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        <h2 style="margin-bottom: 40px; width: 100%; text-align: center;">Get İn Touch</h2>
    <div><input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="Name">
     {% for err in form.name.errors %}
     <small class="text-danger">
        {{ err }}
     </small>
     {% endfor %}
    
    </div>
    <div><input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" name="E-mail">
        {% for err in form.name.errors %}
        <small class="text-danger">
           {{ err }}
        </small>
        {% endfor %}
    
    </div>
    <div><input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="Subject">
        {% for err in form.name.errors %}
        <small class="text-danger">
           {{ err }}
        </small>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div><textarea name="" id="" cols="66" rows="10" style="display: block;"     placeholder="Message" name="Message"></textarea>
        {% for err in form.name.errors %}
        <small class="text-danger">
           {{ err }}
        </small>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="button">
    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Send an email</button>
   


</div>
    </div> 
    
    
    
    </form>
```

this is my form,

```
class Form(forms.ModelForm):
Name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
Email = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
Subject = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
Message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
class Meta:
    model = AppModel
    fields = "__all__"
```

this is my model,

```
class AppModel(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50,name='Name')
email = models.CharField(max_length=100,name='Email')
subject = models.CharField(max_length=50,name='Subject')
message = models.TextField(name='Message')
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not give the HTML input fields a proper name, these should match with your Django form, so since your Django form, to make matters worse, you used a different name than the attribute, while not explicitly a problem, it is not good practice.

We can work with a model like:

```
class AppModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)  # 🖘 no name=…
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)  # 🖘 no name=…
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50)  # 🖘 no name=…
    message = models.TextField()  # 🖘 no name=…
```

so this means that the `ModelForm` will use `name`, `email`, `subject` and `message` as names for the fields, so you can override these with:

```
class Form(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = AppModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

But we don't have to, since this is what the Django `ModelForm` will already do for us:

```
class Form(forms.ModelForm):
    # no name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    # no email = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    # no subject = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    # no message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = AppModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Now finally the HTML form names need to match with this, so:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <!-- … -->

    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name">

    <!-- … -->
    
    <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" name="email">
    
    <!-- … -->
    
    <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="subject">

    <!-- … -->
    
    <textarea name="message" id="" cols="66" rows="10" style="display: block;" placeholder="Message" name="Message"></textarea>
    
    <!-- … -->
    
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much sir, it worked ı m so glad